# Core Data entity lacks its attributes after being returned in a method

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I am experiencing an issue where i have a method that is supposed to return a Core Data entity object that is fetched from a context for the current thread.

When I compile and run the project in DEBUG-mode all works fine, but when the app is run as RELEASE a strange behavior occurs. The returned object lacks its attributes (they are either nil or 0). The application is using ARC to manage memory.

The implementation works using a category on NSManagedObject with a metod like this:

```
- (id)threadLocalSelf {
    return [self selfInContext:[NSManagedObjectContext threadLocalContext]];
}

- (id)selfInContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {
    NSAssert(context, @"context cannot be nil!");
    if(context == self.managedObjectContext)
        return self;

    NSManagedObjectID *objectID = [self objectID];
    if([objectID isTemporaryID])
        [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"objectID cannot be temporary when fetching self in another context!"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObject *_self = [context existingObjectWithID:objectID error:&error];
    if(error)
        [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"Failed to fetch self: %@ in context: %@, error: %@", objectID, context, error];

    NSAssert(_self, @"context: %@ does not contain an object with objectID: %@", context, objectID);

    NSLog(@"Returning _self: %@", _self);

    return _self;
}
```

[NSManaged threadLocalContext] creates a new NSManagedObjectContext for the current thread.

The problem here is that when NSLogging out the object that is about to be returned everything seems fine. All attributes and information about the entity is correct.

However - when logging out the object AFTER it has been returned (like shown below) all attributes are nil or 0. This behavior only happen in RELEASE and not DEBUG.

```
Foo * bar = [baz threadLocalSelf];
NSLog(@"Foo object: %@", bar);
```

The above code results in the object being correctly logged out from within the method, but the NSLog right after has empty attributes. While the ObjectID is correct in both cases and the object is not nil itself.

Any ideas as to what could possibly cause this issue is much appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your thread new context is being released after it is allocated and used.

```
- (id)threadLocalSelf {
    return [self selfInContext:[NSManagedObjectContext threadLocalContext]/*released at the end of method*/];
}
```

Comment: No problems, glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see this behavior only in release builds is because the `NSManagedObjectContext` is being put into an autorelease pool in debug builds, but the ARC optimizer is releasing it immediately in release builds.  You can replicate this in your debug builds by causing the autorelease pool to drain right away:

```
- (id)threadLocalSelf {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return [self selfInContext:[NSManagedObjectContext threadLocalContext]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the DEBUG/RELEASE difference!