# Why does an unsaved managedObject lose its managedObjectContext

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Currently, I am developing an app to book cars. All booking related data are stored in an entity 'Bookings'. As some attributes of 'Bookings' or relationships between 'Bookings' and other enties are mandatory I decided to add all managedObjects of entity 'Bookings' to their own managedObjectContext. This context will also be stored in a separate variable to avoid losing it. This works fine unless I'll sign (enterprise store or adhoc) my app and deploy it. ARC is enabled.

**Class Bookings interface**

```
@interface Bookings : NSManagedObject {
@private
     NSManagedObjectContext *mContext;
}

@end
```

**Class Bookings implementation**

```
@implementation Bookings {

    + (Bookings *)booking {
         NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:concurrencyType];
         [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[self persistentStoreCoordinator]];

         Bookings *object = (Bookings*)[[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:[self entityForName:pName] insertIntoMarenagedObjectContext:context];
         [object setSomeReservationData:...];
         ...

         // here I store the context in an ivar of my booking object
         [object->mContext = context];

         return object;
    }
}
```

At this state the Booking object will not be saved!

**Class BookingsVC**

```
Bookings *booking = [Bookings booking];
NSLog(@"Context: %@", [booking managedObjectContext]);
```

Nothing saved or altered but context is null.

**Console output on device (adhoc signed and deployed via iPhone-Configurator or Testflight)**

```
... Context: (null)
```

**Console output on simulator or device (adhoc signed but installed via Xcode)**

```
... Context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x893c520>
```

So why does an unsaved managedObject lose its managedObjectContext and how can this be avoided? Is it a bug or the expected behavior?

Comment: How is `mContext` declared?

Comment: It's declared as `NSManagedObjectContext *mContext`. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1):

Your context is nullified at the end of your function. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837104/core-data-entity-lacks-its-attributes-after-being-returned-in-a-method/15837196?noredirect=1#comment22533394_15837196)
Your object is disowned by the context making all its properties null, in debug mode there exists an autorelease pool keeping the context from being deallocated.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Didn't kown about the DEBUG/RELEASE differences either. But I can't see any relationship to my issue, as the reported behaviour (nullifying or zero values) don't match with my problem. To avoid losing the context of my object I decided to store it in an ivar. Therefore, shouldn't be the retainCount finally 1 (+1 by alloc, +1 by assigning, -1 release).